# python: generate numeric column to column with string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and it's a part of a column

```
category
Search
Search
Онлайн-магазин
Онлайн-магазин
Форумы и отзывы
Онлайн-магазин
Форумы и отзывы
Агрегатор
Информационный ресурс
Онлайн-магазин
Телеком
Онлайн-магазин
```

I need to create column with category, converted to numeric.
I mean

```
category   numeric_category
Search     1
Search     1
Онлайн-магазин    2
Онлайн-магазин    2
Форумы и отзывы   3
Онлайн-магазин    2
Форумы и отзывы   3
Агрегатор   4
Информационный ресурс   5
Онлайн-магазин   2
Телеком   6
Онлайн-магазин   2
```

How can I do that? using `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['numeric_category'] = pd.factorize(df.category)[0] + 1
```

Then you can also convert it to `category` for saving memory:

```
df['numeric_category'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.category)[0] + 1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['a','s','a']})
print (df)
  category
0        a
1        s
2        a

df['numeric_category'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.category)[0] + 1)
print (df)
  category numeric_category
0        a                1
1        s                2
2        a                1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict={}
for item in df.category:
    if item not in dict:
        dict[item]=len(dict)+1

print "category\t"+"numeric_category"

for item in df.category:
    print "%s\t%s"%(item,dict[item])
```